# No dotted line with networkx drawn on basemap

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, matplotlib-basemap

I try to draw dotted edges with `networkx` on a `basemap` line. Everything works just fine, except `style= 'dotted'`. After setting this flag, nothing is changed. I still get a normal solid edge. Has anybody an idea, what I could change to get a dotted or dashed line on the map? Where is my mistake?

Here is my full script:

```
import networkx as nx
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
geodict={'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 13, 13: 14, 14: 15, 15: 16, 16: 17, 17: 18, 18: 19, 19: 20, 20: 21, 21: 22}, 'Name': {0: 'Bremen', 1: 'Passau', 2: 'Wolgagebiet', 3: 'Ellis Island', 4: 'Nebraska', 5: 'Berlin', 6: 'Prag', 7: 'München', 8: 'Frankfurt am Main', 9: 'Dresden', 10: 'Bresslau', 11: 'Königsberg', 12: 'Moskau', 13: 'Warschau', 14: 'Buenos Aires', 15: 'Chicago', 16: 'Philadelphia', 17: 'Cleveland', 18: 'Detroit', 19: 'Milwaukee', 20: 'Baltimore', 21: 'Rio de Janeiro'}, 'lat': {0: 53.075878, 1: 48.573333, 2: 51.7, 3: 40.698611, 4: 41.583333, 5: 52.518611, 6: 50.088611, 7: 48.137221999999994, 8: 50.110556, 9: 51.049259, 10: 51.11, 11: 54.733332999999995, 12: 55.75, 13: 52.216667, 14: -34.599722, 15: 41.881944, 16: 39.952222, 17: 41.482222, 18: 42.3316, 19: 43.052222, 20: 39.286389, 21: -22.908333}, 'lng': {0: 8.807311, 1: 13.456944, 2: 46.75, 3: -74.04, 4: -99.583333, 5: 13.408332999999999, 6: 14.421389000000001, 7: 11.575556, 8: 8.682222, 9: 13.73836, 10: 17.032222, 11: 20.483333, 12: 37.616667, 13: 21.033333, 14: -58.381944, 15: -87.627778, 16: -75.163889, 17: -81.669722, 18: -83.0475, 19: -87.955833, 20: -76.615, 21: -43.196389}, 'Anz': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 0, 15: 0, 16: 0, 17: 0, 18: 0, 19: 0, 20: 0, 21: 0}}
geopos= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(geodict)
position={}
m = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=-20,lat_0=30,resolution='l')
m.shadedrelief()

font = {'family': 'serif',
        'color':  'black',
        'weight': 'normal',
        'size': 12,
        }
for line in geopos.itertuples():
    position[line.Name] = m(line.lng, line.lat)
    if line.Anz==1:
        if line.Name=='Nebraska':
            plt.text(position[line.Name][0] - 150000, position[line.Name][1] + 100000, line.Name, font)
        elif line.Name == 'Bremen':
            plt.text(position[line.Name][0] - 250000, position[line.Name][1] - 200000, line.Name, font)
        else:
            plt.text(position[line.Name][0] - 200000, position[line.Name][1] - 180000, line.Name, font)
G=nx.DiGraph()
G2=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('Bremen',weight=10, label='Bremen')
G.add_node('Wolgagebiet',weight=1)
G.add_node('Passau',weight=1)
G.add_node('Ellis Island',weight=10)
G.add_node('Nebraska',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Passau',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Ellis Island',weight=10)
G2.add_node('Berlin',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Prag',weight=1)
G2.add_node('München',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Frankfurt am Main',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Dresden',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Bresslau',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Königsberg',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Moskau',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Warschau',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Buenos Aires',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Chicago',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Philadelphia',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Cleveland',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Detroit',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Milwaukee',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Baltimore',weight=1)
G2.add_node('Rio de Janeiro',weight=1)

G.add_edge('Wolgagebiet','Bremen')
G.add_edge('Passau','Bremen')
G.add_edge('Bremen','Ellis Island')
G.add_edge('Ellis Island', 'Nebraska')

G2.add_edge('Berlin','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Prag','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('München','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Frankfurt am Main','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Dresden','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Bresslau','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Königsberg','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Moskau','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Warschau','Bremen')
G2.add_edge('Bremen','Buenos Aires')
G2.add_edge('Ellis Island','Chicago')
G2.add_edge('Ellis Island','Philadelphia')
G2.add_edge('Ellis Island','Cleveland')
G2.add_edge('Ellis Island','Detroit')
G2.add_edge('Ellis Island','Milwaukee')
G2.add_edge('Ellis Island','Baltimore')
G2.add_edge('Bremen','Rio de Janeiro')

pos = dict((land, position[land]) for land in G.nodes())
pos2 = dict((land, position[land]) for land in G2.nodes())
print(G.edges)
lllon = -80
urlon = 80
lllat = 20
urlat = 50

xmin, ymin = m(lllon, lllat)
xmax, ymax = m(urlon, urlat)

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_xlim([xmin, xmax])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G2, pos2, with_labels=True,node_size=[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]],node_color='grey')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G2, pos2, width = 1,style='dotted',edge_color='grey')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, with_labels=True,node_size=[[200, 20, 20, 200, 20]],node_color='red')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, color='white', width = [7,3,3,3,3],style='dashdot',edge_color='b')
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you update your code so that 1) It uses `style='dotted'` somewhere and 2) It is simplified enough that we can copy and paste it to run it?  We don't have `'bremen-stationen.csv'` on our machines.

Comment: edited as requested, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This smells terribly like a bug to me -- maybe you should bring it up with the `networkx` developers. For now, I found a workaround. When calling `help(nx.draw_networkx_edges)`, you get the following piece of information:

> ### Returns
>
> matplotlib.collection.LineCollection
>       `LineCollection` of the edges
>
> list of matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch
>       `FancyArrowPatch` instances of the directed edges
>
> Depending whether the drawing includes arrows or not.

The [networkx documentation pages](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) don't mention the second possibility, btw. Anyway, as you do use arrows, you can retrieve said `list` of `FancyArrowPatch`s and set the line style for these 'by hand'. In short, if you alter the last few lines of your code like this:

```
collection = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G2, pos2, width = 2,edge_color='grey')
for patch in collection:
    patch.set_linestyle('dotted')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, with_labels=True,node_size=[[200, 20, 20, 200, 20]],node_color='red')

collection = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, color='white', width = [7,3,3,3,3],edge_color='b')
for patch in collection:
    patch.set_linestyle('dashdot')

plt.show()
```

you get your dotted lines:

[image]

Tested on python 3.6 (2.7 gives me an error about the character encoding). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick, I will open a issue in Guthub.