# How to specify edge style(solid, dotted, dashed) when using draw_circular function in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

How to specify edge style(solid, dotted, dashed) when using draw_circular function in networkx? I know I can specify edge color using edge_color attribute, is there a similar one like "edge_style"?

Answer (score 3):

the keyword 'style' controls the edge_style you can use '-' for solid or '--' for dashed

```
nx.draw_networkx( XXXXXXXX,  style='--')
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammed! I actually have several sets of edges which take different styles. That's why I need to add these edge sets separately.

Comment: do you mean some edges are dotted and some are dashed and so on..?

Comment: Yes, some edges are dotted, and others take other styles.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. What did: using `patch.set_linestyle()` for edges after calling `draw_networkx_edges()` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51148746/3077484)

Answer (score 1):

you can use style parameter in draw_networkx() function as below:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=None, style='-')
```

Edge line style e.g.: ‘-‘, ‘–’, ‘-.’, ‘:’ or words like ‘solid’ or ‘dashed’.
see this link:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html

Answer (score 0):

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#draw-networkx-edges

I have not tested this yet, but it appears that this method lets you define an `edgeList`, and it will only draw those edges of the graph. I assume one could store the sets of edges in separate lists, then draw them in 2 batches to have different edges with different styles.